# Can I track only my TODO tasks in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Is there a way that I can only filter out my own **TODO** tasks in Visual Studio?

Currently there are several developers working and they add their own **TODO**. Finally, if I view my Task List, there are a whole lot of TODOs listed and I can hardly figure out which are mine.

I tried searching some VS sites, but didn't find anything helpful. How do I filter only my own **TODOs**, or at least all the **TODOs** in the files that I have touched? I am using VS 2010.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add custom tags that will be tracked in the task list, as [explained on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zce12xx2.aspx).

So, you can add a tag for your stuff only, though you may be able to add `todo me`, meaning that it will still be tracked by the generic `todo` task list.

Comment: Is this supposed to work in VS2019? Doesn't for me.

Comment: @user3285954 - I tried it on VS2019 and it doesn't seem to work for new tokens, so something is broken there. You can report it as a bug through their problem reporting feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019